# Given two sets of vectors, is there a relationship that describes whether one of them is "orthogonal" to another?

Tags: vector-spaces

We saw this theorem regarding orthogonal vector subspaces:

> Have
>
> $$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_k\}\\ B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_r\}$$
>
> Bases of vector subspaces $S$ and $T$ respectively. Then:
>
> $$A \perp B \iff a_i \perp b_j \ \ \ \forall i = 1,...,k \ \ , \ \
> > \forall j = 1,...,r$$

It seemed a bit confusing. Somebody said something along the lines of

> So basically, two subspaces are orthogonal if their bases are too.

But I couldn't quite agree and I'm not sure why.

For starters, there isn't such thing as THE base. There can be multiple bases, right?

Anyway, that's not really what got me thinking: it was his statement "[bases] are orthogonal".

I scourged my book, but I never actually found a definition about whether one base is orthogonal to another.

So my question boils down to this:

**Given two sets of vectors, is there a relationship that describes whether one of them is "orthogonal" to another?**

The closest thing I found would be a definition about orthogonal **subspaces**:

> For two subspaces $S,T$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, they are orthogonal if $$x \cdot y = 0 \ \ \forall x \in S \ \ \forall y \in T$$

So, if I had to define the "orthogonality" relationship between two vector sets $A,B$, by analogy I would say that $A \perp B$ if:

$$x \cdot y = 0 \ \ \forall x \in A \ \ \forall y \in B$$

But then again, I can't find this definition in my book.

Answer (score 1):

For two subspaces to be orthogonal (i.e. any two vectors from these are orthogonal), it suffices that their bases be orthogonal.

This is because a subspace is the set of vectors spanned by the basis, i.e. all possible linear combinations of the basis vectors. So if you express two vectors as linear combinations of their respective basis, you directly see that their dot product is null.
$$x\cdot y=\sum\alpha_k\ a_k\cdot\sum\beta_r\ b_r=\sum\sum\alpha_k\beta_r\ a_k\cdot b_r=0$$

Indeed a subspace can have different bases, and the property holds for any base of the subspace that you take (because the other base vectors belong to the subspace too, and are orthogonal to the vectors in the other subspace).